# React Hooks Async Best Practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Now with use `useEffect`s, there is a substitute for `componentDidMount` into a React Component with Hooks.

Scenario "initial unique call to a server":

To accomplish this, DependencyList (second argument of `useEffect`) in `useEffect` should every time an empty array otherwise the application will send every state change a fetch call to the server.

it means, this is the best practice to getData

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("useEffect, fetchData here");
}, []);
```

Is it best practice, to use `[]` as DependencyList param to disable server requesting every state changing?

Link to github
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326

Comment: React is developing `React Suspense` that's designed to make things like that easier.  In the mean time I created my own component that makes things like this easier.  I'll post a snippet below if your interested.   ps: Yes, using `[]` is what I do, but do be aware of closures if doing this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is the best approach.

From the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect):

> Passing in an empty array [] of inputs tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from the component, so that effect would run only on mount and clean up on unmount; it won’t run on updates.

`useEffect` is a very powerful, and my favorite, hook. You can monitor one or more variables for state changes by passing them into the second parameter array, or you can just listen for mounting and unmounting with the approach that you're using.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you want the server to be called whenever some parameter changes. If you want the same async call regardless, you can use `[]` as the second parameter.

However, if you are for example displaying a profile page of a user where each page has a userID state/prop, you should pass in that ID as a value into the second parameter of `useEffect` so that the data will be refetched for a new user ID. `componentDidMount` is insufficient here as the component might not need remounting if you go directly from user A to user B's profile.

In the traditional classes way, you would do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.id !== this.state.id) {
    this.fetchData();
  }
}
```

With hooks, that would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
  this.fetchData();
}, [id]);
```

Try running the code below and see the result. Change the id to 2 for instance to see that `useEffect` is run again.

```js
function Todo() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState(null);
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (id == null || id === '') {
      return;
    }
    
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        setTodo(data);
      });
  }, [id]); // useEffect will trigger whenever id is different.

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={id} onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)}/>
      <br/>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(todo, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You should read up on [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) so that you know what you can/cannot do with it.